# Angular library project using router.navigate won't navigate to other module's route

Tags: angular, module, shared-libraries, router

I have a separate Angular library project for authentication and in some cases, I need to navigate to the root route of one of the applications using this library project for its authentication.

The line `this._router.navigate(['/'])` doesn't do anything, currently, I'm assuming, because this library's module doesn't have routing configuration.

### Question

Would it be possible for the application project utilizing this authentication library project to initialize it in some way as to allow it to navigate to one of the routes defined in the application's module?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am struggling with my own auth library for this exact reason and I can't really find any documentation on the issue (which usually means I am missing something fundamental).

Comment: Well... maybe you need to "preseveSymlinks".
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317993/angular-library-route-module-does-not-work-when-imported-in-application