# External component requiring RouterModule

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular8

Say I have a very basic component that is part of an **Angular component library** that looks like the following :

#### mycomponent.module.html

```html
<div>
    <a routerLink="/">
</div>
```

#### mycomponent.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html'
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

#### mycomponent.module.ts

```js
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MyComponentComponent} from './mycomponent.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponentComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  exports: [MyComponentComponent]
})
export class MyComponentModule{ }
```

I now publish this library, and use this component in another project **by including MyComponentModule** as such :

#### myproject.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, MyComponentModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class MyProjectModule{}
```

I then get the following stacktrace :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
    at NullInjector.get (vendor.js:131635)
    at resolveToken (vendor.js:146553)
    at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:146479)
    at StaticInjector.get (vendor.js:146329)
```

Although `MyProjectModule` uses `RouterModule`, and works properly if I add a `<a routerLink="/"></a>`, it does not work if the routerLink is inside a **child component from an external library**. Navigation works properly anywhere else in the app. What is going on here ?

Comment: I think you need `BrowserModule` in your `MyProjectModule` maybe.

Comment: It's already there (albeit in another module, as `MyProjectModule` is not the root module) - the error messages sounds like it's something related to routing

Comment: Might be a silly thing but is your route set up for `"/"` with the RouterModule?

Comment: Sadly it is... :(

Comment: Could this help maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317993/angular-library-route-module-does-not-work-when-imported-in-application

Comment: Good find thank you, but I get the same results even when adding the `preserveSymlinks` option

Comment: Ok how about adding this in your NgModule `RouterModule.forRoot(your-routes-here), `

Comment: Which module ? `MyProjectModule` already has these, and I don't want to add this in the `MyComponentModule` as this is part of an external library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after a while.

**Do not import an external library with `paths` in `tsconfig.json` if it requires service injection** (e.g. routing).

The external library containing `MyComponentModule` was *artificially imported* using the `paths` object in `tsconfig.json`, e.g :

```
"paths": {
  "my-library": ["../my-library/lib/src/"]
}
```

Although this made development easier by hot reloading my app when modifying the library, **it prevents modules from being injected properly**.